# How to open app from facebook's native app in ios 8.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, url-scheme

I am posting some content with URL to facebook and twitter. when we tap on URL suppose that is in facebook it will open my app using [iOS Custom URL Schemes](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) and [deep link](http://fokkezb.nl/2013/09/20/url-schemes-for-ios-and-android-2/).

I have used and created **iOS Custom URL Schemes** in my application to open it from different native app or browser using URL.

It's working properly when I am trying it from safari and facebook's native app in iOS 7.2

**Please Note : Unfortunately it's not working only when I am trying to open it from facebook's native app from iOS 8.4**

I am not sure that it's issue  of either with facebook's app version or iOS version.

Please give your valuable suggestion.

```
var IS_IPAD = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null, 
IS_IPHONE = !IS_IPAD && ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) != null) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) != null)),
IS_IOS = IS_IPAD || IS_IPHONE,
IS_ANDROID = !IS_IOS && navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i) != null,
IS_MOBILE = IS_IOS || IS_ANDROID;

 if (IS_IOS) {
     window.location = "myapp://view?id=123";
     setTimeout(function() {
         // If the user is still here, open the App Store
         if (!document.webkitHidden) {
            // Replace the Apple ID following '/id'
            window.location = 'http://itunes.apple.com/app/id1234567';
         }
     }, 25);
 }
```